# Is it normal to see incoming connections from google?

Tags: networking, firewall

My logs are showing attempted connections from google, whenever i browse the internet. This log:

```
Jan 20 12:30:50 HOSTNAME kernel: Dropped: IN=wlp7s0 OUT= MAC=30:3a:64:02:f1:a7:e8:e7:32:c1:75:69:08:00 SRC=216.58.195.65 DST=10.113.194.49 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=57 ID=2933 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=40324 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
```

tells me that my firewall is dropping this incoming connection. As my firewall rule says:

```
-A INPUT -i all -p tcp -m tcp --sport 443 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m comment --comment "https" -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m comment --comment "https" -j ACCEPT
```

which means to me that i am only allowing incoming packets to my port 443 only if I initialized it. This leads me to believe that Google is trying to initialize a connection. Is this okay to block? Is this normal?

I am using firefox.

Comment: Are you using Chrome?

Comment: no i am using firefox

Comment: This is not an incoming connection. It's a `RST` packet that Google is sending, which is a response to an outgoing connection.

Comment: `443` is the source port, not the destination port, so it's coming from Google's port 443, not going to your port 443.

Comment: @Barmar yes that's what my rules state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a new connection. It's just a `RST` (TCP Reset) packet sent by the server at Google's premises to indicate a finished/closed connection (TCP state FIN_WAIT). Maybe your system removes the connection too early from it's table, so your firewall misinterprets the RST package as a new connection.

Also, your iptables rules look a little bit odd. In order to allow HTTPS web browsing it should suffice to use:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport=443 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

I see no reason to accept INCOMING connections (RELATED/ESTABLISHED) from anywhere assuming a source port of 443 (--sport=443)

If you aren't running any server activity, you may restrict INPUT chain by using a default policy:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Then, you can open specific ports, if needed, eg. for running a local web server:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport=80 -d <<your-host-here>> -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: okay i understand why im getting the rst packet now. However the rule is directly from the iptables.rules, not the command to create one. I have to accept incoming packets directed from port 443 so the connection can be kept, else it will be dropped, since my policy is DROP.

Comment: @JShade01 The rules for `RELATED,ESTABLISHED` generally shouldn't be applied to specific ports. They should be at the beginning of the rules, to allow any responses to outgoing connections.

Comment: @Barmar The way i have my firewall, dont want to allow just any packets coming in even if i did initiate the sequence. Personal preference.