# Why am I receiving unsolicited incoming connections from the sites I visit?

Tags: firewall

This only happens while browsing. I have one of those routers that doesn't even block incoming traffic, so my computer's firewall has to do all the work. In the log below I used Firefox, but this happens with any browser. In my Firefox, HTTP2, web workers, service workers, WebRTC and a lot of other stuff are disabled/blocked, so it's really a mystery to me how the servers are managing to request unsolicited connections to my computer. This happens on several sites when browsing them, but not all.

```
Date    Time  Direction                  Process path                  Protocol    Source IP     Src Port     Dest. IP    Dest.Port  Action                                 Window title
17/04 16:23:59 | Out | C:\program files\mozilla firefox\firefox.exe    | TCP  | 10.0.0.3        | 50755 | 204.79.197.200  | 443   | Allowed | Startpage.com - The world's most private search engine - Mozilla Firefox
17/04 16:23:59 | In  | -                                               | TCP  | 204.79.197.200  | 443   | 10.0.0.3        | 50730 | Blocked | 
17/04 16:23:59 | In  | -                                               | TCP  | 204.79.197.200  | 443   | 10.0.0.3        | 50735 | Blocked | 
17/04 16:23:59 | In  | -                                               | TCP  | 204.79.197.200  | 443   | 10.0.0.3        | 50735 | Blocked | 
17/04 16:25:25 | Out | C:\program files\mozilla firefox\firefox.exe    | TCP  | 10.0.0.3        | 50766 | 37.252.238.25   | 443   | Allowed | unsolicited incoming connections at DuckDuckGo - Mozilla Firefox
17/04 16:25:25 | In  | -                                               | TCP  | 37.252.238.25   | 443   | 10.0.0.3        | 50766 | Blocked | 
17/04 16:29:50 | Out | C:\program files\mozilla firefox\firefox.exe    | TCP  | 10.0.0.3        | 50785 | 201.48.71.43    | 443   | Allowed | Bing - Mozilla Firefox
17/04 16:29:51 | Out | C:\program files\mozilla firefox\firefox.exe    | TCP  | 10.0.0.3        | 50786 | 201.48.71.43    | 443   | Allowed | Bing - Mozilla Firefox
17/04 16:29:51 | Out | C:\program files\mozilla firefox\firefox.exe    | TCP  | 10.0.0.3        | 50787 | 201.48.71.43    | 443   | Allowed | Bing - Mozilla Firefox
17/04 16:29:51 | Out | C:\program files\mozilla firefox\firefox.exe    | TCP  | 10.0.0.3        | 50788 | 201.48.71.43    | 443   | Allowed | Bing - Mozilla Firefox
17/04 16:29:54 | In  | -                                               | TCP  | 201.48.71.43    | 443   | 10.0.0.3        | 50788 | Blocked | 
17/04 17:03:12 | Out | C:\program files\mozilla firefox\firefox.exe    | TCP  | 10.0.0.3        | 50986 | 151.101.1.69    | 443   | Allowed | Super User - Mozilla Firefox
17/04 17:03:12 | Out | C:\program files\mozilla firefox\firefox.exe    | TCP  | 10.0.0.3        | 50987 | 151.101.1.69    | 443   | Allowed | Super User - Mozilla Firefox
17/04 17:03:18 | In  | -                                               | TCP  | 151.101.1.69    | 443   | 10.0.0.3        | 50986 | Blocked | 
17/04 17:03:18 | In  | -                                               | TCP  | 151.101.1.69    | 443   | 10.0.0.3        | 50987 | Blocked |
```

There are many other examples, but they all follow the same pattern: I access the site, which creates a connection to a specific IP, then one or more unsolicited incoming connection attempts happen coming from the same IP.

Anyone knows what, why and how this is happening?

Comment: And your browser has HTTP2 disabled for what reason exactly?...

Answer (score 2):

No, I think your computer's firewall is lying to you.

Judging by the choice of local and remote ports, it's probably seeing perfectly normal response packets that belong to an existing outbound connection, but is unable to associate them with that connection for some reason.

To know whether a connection is incoming or outgoing, a firewall has to be stateful – it pays attention to every TCP packet and remembers the corresponding address & port pairs. For example, it knows that all packets with local address (10.0.0.3, 50766) and remote address (37.252.238.25, 443) belong to an outbound connection your browser made.

When a reply packet comes in, the firewall looks at its connection table and sees that the address pair (37.252.238.25, 443) to (10.0.0.3, 50766) is already known – the packet isn't a new connection, it's just a response to an existing (outbound) connection and needs to be allowed.

But if the state information gets desynchronized for some reason – e.g. the hosts themselves think a connection is still open, but the firewall has forgotten it already – then it will not be able to determine the type of incoming packet easily. In this case, the firewall no longer *knows* that the incoming packet belongs to a connection that was originally outbound – so it ends up associating it with a separate "inbound" entry instead.

For example, a possible cause is that your computer has just now *sent* the "connection close" FIN packet, but the remote server has *not yet received* it (because data transfer is not instant), and is still happily sending you packets. If your firewall immediately forgets the connection upon seeing the outgoing FIN, then of course it will be unable to recognize those incoming packets as still belonging to the same connection. (Half-closed connections are valid in TCP, but I wouldn't put it past a firewall to not realize this.)

This sometimes also happens when the firewall has a very small limit of states, e.g. I've seen home routers which cannot track more than 50 or 100 states at once (that includes not just TCP connections, but UDP streams as well – e.g. each DNS request via UDP makes a new state so that the response could be allowed through). Similarly, some firewalls have a very short state expiry time – they might forget TCP connections as soon as they're idle for a minute or two, even though it's completely normal for a connection to remain idle for quite a bit longer than that.

(Sometimes firewalls are over-eager to reject things that both hosts would consider to be normal. For example, when browsers started experimenting with TCP Fast Open, my ISP-provided home router at the time blocked *all* TFO packets based on its belief that "SYN packets cannot contain data" and yelled "Intrusion alert" in its logs every single time. I believe this is a huge part of why QUIC is being developed as a separate thing from TCP.)

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/questions/1169786/is-it-normal-to-see-incoming-connections-from-google for a similar situation.